# Setting tabActivity title in android

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a `TabActivity` in which there are two tabs , tabs may increase in future.So i need to change the title of `MyTabActivity` from anyone of them according to situation so that it is visible from all the tabs.

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  tabContext = this;

  setTitle("My App Name");

  final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1).setIndicator(TAB_1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)).setContent(new Intent(this, first.class)));

  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2).setIndicator(TAB_2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2)).setContent(new Intent(this, second.class)));

   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

   public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
             setTabTitle();

      }
   });

   tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_1);
   }
}
```

i have written `setTabTitle()` function to set my `tabActivity` title.

```
public void setTabTitle()
{
    PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
    String tabtitle = prefManager.getTitle();
    tabContext.setTitle("My App Name" + " " + tabtitle);
}
```

i am trying to change the title of `MyTabActivity` from the TAB_1(**ListActivity**) or TAB_2(**Activity**) when i get some data in these two activities .But when i change the tab then only the title gets changed because i have called it in (`setOnTabChangedListener`).But i want to change it as soon as i get some data in any one of my activity and calling this `setTabTitle` function.

i have tried two things as of now.Making `setTabTitle()` as static and calling it from two activities as `MyTabActivity.setTabTitle("My Title")` but its not working.

```
 public static void setTabTitle(String title)
{
    tabContext.setTitle("My App Name" + " " + title);
}
```

Other is as suggested by a member of this forum

```
   MyTabActivity myTabs = (MyTabActivity) this.getParent();
    myTabs.setTitle("This is First cool Activity");
```

But both of these is not working .Do i need to do some kind of REFRESH in activity ?.

Help me how to do this.

Thanks